# Do I have an SSD and a hard drive on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: hard-drive, partition, ssd

I looked at the details provided in  my
system report/storage and I noticed that it appears I have a hard drive of 499.05GB and an additional SSD drive of 499.42GB. Does this mean I have 1TB of data? I only have 139GB available so do I have 500GB 'hiding' somewhere? (If so where??) 
I am unsure how to interpret this information- why does it list both storage types? Is it duplicating the information?

> Macintosh HD:
>
> Available:    139.8 GB (139,800,666,112 bytes)
>   Capacity: **499.05 GB** (499,046,809,600 bytes)
>   Mount Point:  /
>   File System:  Journaled HFS+
>   Writable: Yes
>   Ignore Ownership: No
>   BSD Name: **disk1**
>   Volume UUID:  EF0908C8-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX80333709
>
> Logical Volume:  Revertible:  Yes (unlock and decryption required)
>   Encrypted:    Yes
>   Encryption Type:  AES-XTS
>   Locked:   No
>   LV UUID:  8CC9C88D-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX2002329B
>
> Logical Volume Group:
>   Name:    Macintosh HD   Size:    499.42 GB (499,418,034,176 bytes)
>   Free Space:  18.9 MB (18,903,040 bytes)
>    LVG  UUID: EE040070-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXA83B309
>
> Physical Volumes:
>
> **disk0s2:**     #is this a second disk?
>
> Device Name:  APPLE SSD SM0512G
>   Media Name: APPLE SSD  SM0512G
>   Media   Size:   **499.42 GB** (499,418,034,176 bytes)
>   Medium Type:  **SSD**
>    Protocol:  PCI
>    Internal:  Yes
>   Partition Map Type: GPT(GUID Partition Table)  #does this mean its partitioned?
>   Status: Online
>   S.M.A.R.T. Status:  Verified
>   PV UUID:    A1391405-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX2E8FCDF3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider SSDs being hard drives then you have an SSD and a hard drive on your MBP. It's still only one device with ~500 GB disk space.

The main partition of your SSD is encrypted with FileVault2. While enabling FV2 the main partition is transformed to CoreStorage which is an [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management) - an additional layer between physical disk and file system. The resulting Logical Volume is shown as an additional disk in Disk Utility/diskutil info.

A common partition layout looks like this:

```
disk0 (500.1 GB) → disk0s1 (209.7 MB) EFI
                 ↘︎ disk0s2 (499.4 GB) Macintosh HD
                 ↘︎ disk0s3 (650.0 MB) Recovery HD
```

disk0s2 (Macintosh HD) is mounted to root (`/`)

After converting the disk to CoreStorage, disk0s2 is converted to a Physical Volume which sets up a Logical Volume Group. The existing file system on disk0s2 is shrunk a bit, converted to a Logical Volume and encrypted:

```
disk0 (500.1 GB) → disk0s1 (209.7 MB) EFI
                 ↘︎ disk0s2 (499.4 GB) LVG/PV → disk1    (499.05 GB) LV/Macintosh HD
                                             ↘︎ metadata (~370 MB)
                 ↘︎ disk0s3 (650.0 MB) Recovery HD
```

Now disk1 (~disk0s2) is mounted to root (`/`).

So disk1 is almost congruent to disk0s2 (except some 100 MB at the end of disk0s2 which is used for metadata and isn't encrypted).

---

CoreStorage is not limited to encrypt volumes as FileVault2 "container". Every regular volume can be converted to a CS LVG/PV/LV. Apple uses it to create Fusion Drives and SSDs are usually partitioned/formatted as CoreStorage volumes.